# Pass variable from Java to Batch

Tags: java, batch-file, batch-rename

This Java programm opens a Batch file and passes the string `folderName`

```
public class FolderCreator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{    
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:/Documents/NameFolder.bat folderName");
            p.waitFor();
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }   
    }
}
```

This is the NameFolder.bat file. It shall create a folder with the name from the passed Java variable above.

```
//What do I need to ad here?

if not exist "C:\Desktop\folderName\" mkdir C:\Desktop\folderName
```

What do I need to add to the Batch file?

**EDIT:**

This works

```
if not exist "C:\Desktop\%1\" mkdir C:\Desktop\%1
```

Comment: Are you asking for help with Java or Batch?

Comment: What do I need to add to the batch file

Comment: Does `%1` work?

Comment: Do you receive this `folderName` through the `args`? Why do you want to use a scripting language via Java when there's `java.nio`? You could just create a `Path` that points to the desktop and then `resolve` the folder name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Batch Script

> The following will create a directory only if that directory does not exist

```
if not exist "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\%1" (
  mkdir  "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\%1"
)
```

Assuming you save this to file C:/Documents/NameFolder.bat you just execute it with the same exact Java code

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:/Documents/NameFolder.bat folderName");
```

This will create a `c:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\folderName` directory only if that directory doesn't already exist.

> This is not best practice.  Please read up on executing shell/batch scripts from Java